# What the purpose of Labeled function declarations

Tags: javascript

I've recently come across `Labeled function declarations`. There is not much said about them on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Labeled_function_declarations) website:

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, labeled function declarations are now
>   standardized for non-strict code in the web compatibility annex of the
>   specification.
>
> L: function F() {}

The [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-labelled-function-declarations) doesn't add much details either and there's nothing on the web as well.

Has anyone used them? What's the purpose of them? Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I could gather, the only purpose seems to be support for bad code floating on the web. They cannot be referenced, and are completely useless.

[Brendan Eich, 2012](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/function-declaration-in-labelled-statements):

> People tend to make unnecessary labels, especially in event handlers where javascript: at the front of the HTML attribute value has been seen in the wild. Couple that with a function expression that is not parenthesized, but possibly immediately invoked, and you have real trouble.

The fact that they are useless grammatical relics is the reason why they were gotten rid of.

Comment: as we all know javascript use object every where, so inside object this need arises.  other thing i don't know

Comment: @EaBangalore: Keys in object literals are not labels, the keys and the labels are parsed using very different grammatical rules.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it was my interpretion now things are clear to me

Comment: Somebody at some time thought there was a purpose for these labels or they wouldn't exist.  I'm dying of curiosity to know what that supposed purpose was.