# Labelled arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In the MDN docs for Javascript labels it says this:

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, labeled function declarations are now standardized for non-strict code in the web compatibility annex of the specification.
>
> `L: function F() {}`

However, it seems that I cannot label an arrow function and I was wondering why that was the case. My simplified code is below:

```
horizWin: () => { ... }
vertWin: () => { ... }
[horizWin, vertWin].find(element => element)
```

I am inside Create React App and using ESLint (if that is relevant). My errors are:

1. `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`This is the error for my function labelling which I don't understand.
2. `'horizWin' is not defined` and `'vertWin' is not defined`. Clearly I can't call the label like this but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (supposing that the function labelling was valid).

Comment: Don't you just want `horizWin = () => {}` and `vertWin = () => {}`? Why use labels? Also, as the MDN doc says, you can use function *declarations* with labels, however, arrow functions are *expressions*.

Comment: The moment i read "non-strict" and "web compatibility annex", i turn around and run away as fast as i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A label is not a variable. It is not an object in code you can refer to. It isn't something you can even refer to in general outside of `break` and `continue` statements. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) are very clear about this.

According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277829/what-the-purpose-of-labeled-function-declarations), labeled functions can't even be used for anything. They are merely there for backwards compatibility with old, bad code.

It looks like you might be trying to assign arrow functions to a variable. Labels have nothing to do with this. Simply use variable declarations:

```
let horizWin = () => { ... }
let vertWin = () => { ... }
[horizWin, vertWin].find(element => element)
```

Comment: @j_krl I'd recommend making further questions into proper new questions instead of comments here. In short, `let` or `const` both work, it's just a difference of intent. I don't see any re-assignments in this snippet so `const` won't error.