# Why can labels be applied to all language statements?

Tags: javascript

[According to the ECMAScript standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-labelled-statements), labels can be applied to all statements.

This means that the following lines are valid:

```js
myLabel: throw 'whatever'
```

as well as

```js
function foo() {
  myLabel: return 'whatever'
}

console.log(foo())
```

But these labels appear to be unusable, which begs the question: why are they allowed? (Or maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding)

Comment: Probably because the first release of JavaScript was, more or less, thrown together in a weekend and now we're stuck with a few poor choices from back then … but that's speculation. I doubt the why of a language design choice from quarter of a century ago is documented anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin It seemed like such a good idea at the time!

Comment: You can also do `return "foo"; console.log("bar")`. That's also allowed. JS doesn't differentiate terminal statements from any other statement.

Comment: Probably because it simplifies the grammar. I'd guess it's a legacy inherited from Java, which inherited it from C, which inherited it from Assembler, where you can label any statement.

Comment: Best guess: because C [lets you label statements](https://www.c-programming-simple-steps.com/goto-statement.html) (for GOTO) and [Java as well](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/flow-control/labeled-statements-in-java/). @Bergi you beat me by 20 seconds lol.

Comment: Notice you can do [fancy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469522/1048572) with labelled blocks. But yeah, labelled non-block statements (in which you cannot place a `break` or `continue`) are useless (just like many other forms of allowed code).

Comment: This was before comments were invented, so you could document your code using labels. /s

Comment: @Quentin I note that labels [were not in ECMAScript v1](https://archives.ecma-international.org/1996/TC39/96-002.pdf). So the designed-in-ten-days observation is not strictly relevant.

Comment: @Bergi Yay `myLabel: break myLabel`! (This is still useless)

Answer (score 2):

[According to Brendan Eich, the author of JavaScript](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1597634596354789378), this approach aped Java (the new hotness in 1996), and avoided the need for "dead label analysis":

> Same as Java, IIRC. We didn't want to require engines to do dead label analysis. I know for sure I didn't want to when I first implemented in SpiderMonkey. This has led to unintended transposed javascript: labels (used to be URL schemes), but they're harmless.